# How does scipy.signal.deconvolve work?

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution, python, deconvolution, scipy

The `deconvolve(signal, divisor)` function of `scipy`

```
> Deconvolves `divisor` out of `signal`. Returns the quotient and remainder such that `signal = convolve(divisor, quotient) + remainder`
```

The core codes of `deconvolve` are

```
num = atleast_1d(signal)
den = atleast_1d(divisor)
N = len(num)
D = len(den)
input = ones(N - D + 1, float)
input[1:] = 0
quot = lfilter(num, den, input)
```

It's quite different from any deconvolve methods I ever know, such as the frequency spectrum division.

Can anyone explain those behind the codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deconvolution operation in the code is just finding the impulse response of a filter made up of a numerator which is the signal to be deconvolved and a denominator which is (effectively) the filter to do the deconvolution.

As far as deconvolution algorithms go, it is a little simplistic.